# Response does not match challenge, expected value = '727874710', received='727874710'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I try to add subscription for realtime update facebook api fanpage.
I got the error below:

```
Response does not match challenge, expected value = '727874710', received='727874710'
```

I dont understand what's wrong with it.
Anyone can suggest me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem same for any number of your test requests? Or do you get pass sometime.

Comment: Yes. Any my request. 
Try to test this. http://facfeed.iamm.in.th/index.php?r=setting%2Fgot&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=235543232&hub.verify_token=12345

Comment: Where do you see that message?

Comment: Application setting page when I added the subscription.
When I click Test button I got the message.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending two(!) [UTF-8 byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the start of the response. (hex `EF BB BF`)

Facebook is reading at least the second BOM as garbage. (Probably both since your header does not specify UTF-8 as a character set)

Remove the BOM's so that you're only sending the hub challenge back, and things should work well.

Comment: You are right. Because of this made me crazy all day.
Thank you.